# source of argument about relative primeness of simple closed curves on tori

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I have know this argument for decades.  I have no idea of its source.  If anyone knows (not guesses) its origin, then I would be very appreciative.  My guesses are among Ralph Fox, JHC Whitehead, RH Bing, GT Whyburn, RL Moore.  But a reference as well as a name would be the best outcome.  Even a reference to a textbook with the argument (no guesses please, I can do that myself) would be good.

Here is the argument.

Let K be a continuum (compact connected set) in the plane.  Let K+r
represent the hirozontal translate of K by r units parallel to the
x-axis.

To prove: if r>0, s>0, t=r+s, then if K and K+r are disjoint and
if k and K+s are disjoint, then K and K+t are disjoint.

Proof:

Consider A=K, B=K+r, C=K+t=K+r+s.  Assume A and B are disjoint, and B
and C are disjoint.  This matches the hypothesis.  We must show that A
and C are disjoint.

Let M be a point of greatest height in B and let m be a point of least
height in B.  Let d be 1/3 of the smaller of the two distances d(A,B)
and d(B,C).  The N_d(B) neighborhood of all points no more than d from B
is open and connected.  It is also disjoint from N_d(A) and N_d(C).
There is a polygonal embedded path P from M to m in N_d(B) that never goes
over hight M or below height m.  So P union the vertical ray to +
infinty from M union the vertical ray to - infinity from m is an
embedding T of the real line missing N_d(A) and N_d(C).  The point M-r is
in A and the point M+s is in C.  So A is "to the left" of T and C is "to
the right" of T.  So T separates A from C in the plane and A and C are
disjoint.

Application 1:

Let K be a continuum in the plane and let L be a line segment of length
t with both endpoints in K.  Let r+s=t (all numbers positive).  Then
either there is a line segment parallel to L of length r with both
endpoints in K or a line segment parallel to L if length s with both
endpoints in K.

Proof: Rotate everything until L is parallel to the x-axis and
reinterpret "with both endpoints in K" as "K intersects its traslate by
the length of the segment."

Application 2:

Under the assumption of App. 1, and n is a positive integer, then there
is a line segment of length d/n with both endpoints in K.

Proof: It holds for n=1, and if it holds for n-1, then it holds for n
by App. 1 since App. 1 gives line segments of either length d(n-1)/n
or d/n.

Application 3:

If a simple closed curve represents an element (m,n) in H_1 of a torus,
then gcd(m,n)=1.

Proof:  Lift the simple closed curve to a path in the plane.  Let d be
the lenght of the straight line segment from the beginning to the end of
the path.  Let g=gcd(m,n) and assume g>1.  By App. 3, there is a straight
line segment of length d/g with both endpoints in the path.  But the
endpoints project to the same point in the torus and the original curve
must have been singular.

Application 4:

If a simple closed curve lives in an annulus, then it represents a
generator of pi_1.

Proof: similar to App. 3.